# If I only integrate over one axis (x or y), will P([x, y])=0?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I struggle a bit with integration and probability of a continuous vector variables. I understand that probability of any particular point in an uncountable set is 0. But if I have a vector-values random variable in R^2, and I want to move (integrate) along one axis but not along the other, will probability of such event still be equal to 0? Should I move along both axis to get P>0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. In general if you consider a 2-dimensional random vector $(X,Y)$ and a region $R\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with Lebesgue measure equal to 0 (i.e. $area(R)=0$), then:
$$
P((X,Y)\in R)=\int_{R}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dxdy=0
$$
because you are doing a double integral over a region with area equal to 0 (for example over a line).

We use this fact in proving that if you have two absolutely continuous random variables, then their vector is not guaranteed to be absolutely continuous.

***Proof***

Let $X_1$ be an absolutely continuous random variable and let $X_2=X_1$ (So that $X_2$ is absolutely continuous). Suppose that $(X_1,X_2)$ is absolutely continuous with density $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^+$. Then consider the region $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=y\}$. Since $area(R) = 0$ we have:
$$
P((X_1,X_2)\in R)=\int_{R}f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2=0
$$
but at the same time, by the definition of $X_1$ and $X_2$:
$$
P((X_1,X_2)\in R) = P(\{X_1=X_2\}) = 1
$$
These probabilities should be the same but we found that they are not, and this concludes this proof by contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: my friend, would you be so kind to answer another question about conditional probability that I just posted, if you have a minute? Sorry for asking, my brain just hurts until I can figure that out lol.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726289/conditional-probability-definition-doesnt-make-sense-to-me-when-dealing-with