# Conditional probability definition doesn't make sense (to me) when dealing with uncountable (real) RV's. Please help a confused ML developer.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Just trying to get my math understanding in order.

So my book has a definition for a conditional probability: P(Y|X) = P(Y, X)/P(X).

I understand that X and Y are sets of vectors [Y, X] and the conditional probability is a probability of intersection of 2 sets, renormalized so that the whole set X has a probability of 1.

My problem is that I don't understand how this definition is consistent with the fact that a probability of any particular point in a continuous space is 0 (unless we defined that point not to be 0, but lest assume we didn't).

If X is a vector values continuous random variable in R^n, and Y is in {0, 1}. Then by definition P(Y|X=x) will be undefined at any particular point x, because P(Y, X=x) is 0 and P(X=x) is 0. I understand that I probably supposed to replace P with f for a continuous case and then this formula works, but I's not what was given to me in a definition.

When I study math behind ML algorithms, books always use this P(Y|X=x) and it never make sense. Is there another, better definition of conditional probability for a continuous case?

Just trying to make sense of P(Y|X) is a bit more rigorous way.

If you will answer with measure theory definition of a conditional probability, I will appreciate it but I will not understand it, unfortunately :)

Thank you!

Comment: So, $Y,X$ are two continuous rvs in $\Bbb R^n$ and you want to understand $P(Y|X)$ better? Well, actually $P(Y|X)$ isn't a thing afaik. There is instead the "conditional expectation" $\Bbb E[Y|X]$. Conditional probability makes sense for *events*. $P(Y\in B|A):=P(B\cap A)/P(A)$

Comment: Short answer is that conditional probability is undefined when the conditioning event has $0$ probability.  A somewhat more subtle discussion can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability).

Comment: @FShrike Thank you! But I do talk about events. How do I define a conditional probability of the event P(Y=1|X=0.5) for example, if Y is in {0, 1} (binary classification) and X is in R?

Comment: @lulu then why do all the ML books use P(Y|X) talking about finding a conditional probability of Y given some particular value or a real vector X?

Comment: they should not do so without supplying a context specific definition.  Limit style definitions, as in the article I linked to, are not uncommon.

Comment: @lulu My whole life was a lie lol. Thank you! 

But then how do I assumed to calculate P(Y|X=x)? If we are being rigorous, it's undefined, but ML books, they assume I just use a PMF instead of a P?

Comment: Again, they should supply a definition.  In some contexts, it might be "obvious" what's intended but even then I'd point it out (at least the first time it's used).  It's a bad habit to make your readers guess what you intend

Comment: There will be times when the conditional distribution is part of the construction of the random variables: for example suppose you had a uniform random variable $X \sim U[0,1]$ and a Bernoulli random variable $Y$ with $P(Y=1 \mid X=x)=x$.  But there will be other cases  where you have to find the conditional distribution: if you use limits to avoid division by $0$ this may require care to avoid the Borel–Kolmogorov paradox as in the example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277388/pdf-of-sum-of-exponentials-conditioned-on-equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and two events $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $P(B)>0$, then:
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
If we are talking about random variables, then we have instead the following definition (def. of the conditional density function):

let $X,Y$ be two random variables and let $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{Y}(y)>0$ (where $f_Y$ is the marginal density of $Y$) then we define the conditional density of the vector $(X,Y)$ as:
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|Y=y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
$$
Note that if $X$ is a discrete random variable, then this function is a density of a discrete random variable; similarly if $X$ is an absolutely continuous random variable, then this function is a density of an absolutely continuous random variable.

So I think your question was: "What if $Y$ is continuous?" Well, if so, the density function $f_Y(y)$ is not equal to $P(Y=y)$ as in the discrete case. A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is a density function of an absolutely continuous random variable $Y$ if you can integrate it and $P(Y\leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f(y)dy$ , $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you my friend! I do understand the distinction between P and PDF/PMF, my confusion is that Machine Learning books always use P(Y|X) for a continuous X, like "this logistic regression model takes a vector x1 and returns P(Y=1|X=x1)". So I am confused how is that P(Y=1|X=x1) defined. From your answer, I see that they probably mean PDF/PMF instead of P, am I right, what do you think? Or if I'm not, how do I supposed to understand the statement in my example?

Comment: Mm, if $X$ is continuous, then $P(Y=1|X=x_1)$ is not defined at all.. It's very strange. This probability exists if and only if $P(X=x_1)>0$. You can not conditionate to an event with probability equal to 0. I think that your $X$ is a discrete random variable.. are you sure it's not?

Comment: It's 100% continious. As an example from a book that is available online and for free: page 112, equation 3.4.6. They are talking about maximum likelihood estimation and they condition on particular values of X in a dataset. And X is definitely a continuous RV (I mean it's a float32 in practice, but it is assumed to be continuous in theory). They state it in the same page, in 3.4.5: "Then the minibatch features X are in R^(n×d)". SO they state that X is a real valued RV and then they state that I supposed to use P(Y=yi|X=xi)

https://classic.d2l.ai/d2l-en-pytorch.pdf

Comment: @LucaOnnis it is defined. It’s the notation people use for the regular conditional distribution

Comment: It's defined  only if $P(X=x_1)>0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LucaOnnis Look into regular conditional distributions and/or disintegration theorem. I think it should be covered in Dudley RAP, Billingsley prob and measure, or Kallenberg foundations of modern probability. When conditioning on a set of positive measure $B$, which is OK, we think of restricting the sample space to $B$. One can heuristically think of conditioning on a null event the same way. Unfortunately, this is not rigorously justified, and is in fact wrong, but this heuristic actually does often lead to the right answer.